# How to render modal using ReactDOM.createPortal at application start without causing "Target container is not a DOM element"?

Tags: reactjs

The application I am developing has a modal placehodler that is rendered at application start:

```
<div id={AppConstants.modalRootId} />
```

Modals are rendered into that placeholder using:

```
ReactDOM.createPortal(..., document.getElementById(AppConstants.modalRootId))
```

This has worked fine when modals have been rendered later in time. But now I want to render a modal at application start and I get:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

What is a good way to fix this?

I tried moving the modal placeholder out from `App.js` to `index.html`:

```
<div id="app">         
    <div id="modal-root"></div>
</div>
```

But that did not work. I think the reason is that `ReactDOM.render` replaces the content of the target element.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it is because react overwrites the subtree of the DOMNode you give to `ReactDOM.render()`.

A simple solution to fix this would be to just extract your div outside the div that you are using to render your app. That is..

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="modal-root"></div>
```